# permission android for internet (beside manisfest)

Tags: android, networking, permissions

Beside adding this:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"   /uses-permission
```

to the manifest. What else is necessary for an app to connect to the internet, send an httppost and receive an httpresponse like this:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);


    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

because I get an answer in XML but it tells that the API method (I am using an API) is not found. I think it is a permission problem...or not??

Comment: who tells and what "who" tells?

Comment: Please post the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That permission is the only thing required by Android to give you internet access.

All other errors are due to either a logical error in your code, or mistakes like running network operations on the main thread.